# What means that "gig"?

Tags: idioms

I am reading a blog for preparing job interview.

So What I want to ask is here.

For starters, can you take a look at below sentence?

"Depending on the gig, it might not even matter whether you are a morning person or a night person, or what your typical work week looks like."

What means really that "**Depending on the gig**" above?

And morning person and night person is relative with a human life such as sleep, wake up etc?

Also can I ask a person like "**are you a afternoon person**"?

Finally, What means that "**work week**"?

Is that means about a work ethic?

Comment: Have you looked up any of these terms in the dictionary?

Comment: Did you research this at all??  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gig#gig_Noun_200

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to address your questions as best I can.
"Depending on the gig" means there will be episodic work, like playing in a band at a bar, which would be a "gig". There is also sound engineering work for concerts, events & promotional functions. Anything that is not steady work and involves sessions is a gig. 
A morning person rises in the AM, and a night person usually works graveyard shift, and sleeps in the day.
Do not ask a person if they are an afternoon person, there's no such thing. It's day person, or night person. Afternoon is part of the day, so that is a day person.
A work week just refers to the stresses, deadlines, monotony,down time, productivity, etc.. etc.. that a work week entails. Work week means exactly that, a week at work. For example:

How was your work week?

It was less stressful and much more enjoyable with the boss on vacation.

Comment: A morning person is happy to rise early and likes to go to bed quite early. An evening person finds early rising more difficult and is still alert later in the evening.